# How to handle file paths in distributed environment

Tags: celery, filepath, distributed-computing

I'm working on setting up a distributed celery environment to do OCR on PDF files. I have about 3M PDFs and OCR is CPU-bound so the idea is to create a cluster of servers to process the OCR.

As I'm writing my task, I've got something like this:

```
@app.task
def do_ocr(pk, file_path):
    content = run_tesseract_command(file_path)
    item = Document.objects.get(pk=pk)
    item.content = ocr_content
    item.save()
```

The question I have what the best way is to make the `file_path` work in a distributed environment. How do people usually handle this? Right now all my files simply live in a simple directory on one of our servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your are in linux environment the easiest way is mount a remote filesystem, using sshfs, in the `/mnt` folder foreach node in cluster. Then you can pass the node name to `do_ocr` function and work as all data is local to current node
**For example**, your cluster has N nodes named: node1, ... ,nodeN
Let's configure node1, foreach node mount remote filesystem. Here's a sample node1's /etc/fstab file

```
sshfs#user@node2:/var/your/app/pdfs    /mnt/node2 fuse    port=<port>,defaults,user,noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000        0       0
....
sshfs#user@nodeN:/var/your/app/pdfs    /mnt/nodeN fuse    port=<port>,defaults,user,noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000        0       0
```

In current node (node1) create a symlink named as current server pointing to pdf's path

```
ln -s /var/your/app/pdfs node1
```

Your mnt folder should contain remote's filesystem and a symlink

```
user@node1:/mnt$ ls -lsa
0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      16 apr 12  2016 node1 -> /var/your/app/pdfs
0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      16 apr 12  2016 node2
...
0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      16 apr 12  2016 nodeN
```

Then your function should look like this:

```
import os
MOUNT_POINT = '/mtn'
@app.task
def do_ocr(pk, node_name, file_path):
    content = run_tesseract_command(os.path.join(MOUNT_POINT,node_name,file_path))
    item = Document.objects.get(pk=pk)
    item.content = ocr_content
    item.save()
```

It works like all files are in the current machine but there's remote-logic working for you transparently

Comment: This feels pretty darned right. Is `sshfs` something that's widely used in production environments? Any major gotchas?

Comment: I've been using it in our production environment and it works like a charm, up to this moment :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are multiple ways to handle it, but let's stick to one of the simpliest one:

- since you'd like to process big amount of files using multiple servers, my first suggestion would be to use the same OS in each server, so you won't have to worry about cross-platform compatibility
- using the word 'cluster' indicates that all of those servers should know their mutual state - it adds complexity, try to switch to the farm of stateless workers (by 'stateless' I mean "not knowing about other's" as they should be aware of at least their own state, e.g.: IDLE, IN_PROGRESS, QUEUE_FULL or more if needed)
- for the file list processing part you could use pull or push model:

  - **push model** could be easily implemented by a simple app that crawls the files and dispatches them (e.g.: over SCP, FTP, whatever) to a set of available servers; servers can monitor their local directories for changes and pick up new files to process; it's also **very easy to scale** - just spin up more servers and update the push client (even in runtime); the only limit is your push client's performance
  - pull model is a little bit more tricky, cause you have to handle more complexity; having a set of servers implicates having a proper starting index per node and offset - it will make **error handling more difficult**, plus, **it doesn't scale easily** (imagine adding twice as more servers to speedup the processing and updating indices and offsets properly on each node.. seems like an error-prone solution)
- I assume that the network traffic isn't a big concern - having 3M files to process will generate it somewhere, one way or the other..
- collecting/storing the results is a different ballpark, but here the list of possible solutions is limitless

Comment: So it sounds like your suggestion is to keep the files distributed across all the servers. I think that's a bit of a non-starter due to storage costs. Sorry if my question isn't clear. I guess I'm thinking more about the way that server B will access a file on server A. Is it through distributed file systems? Some sort of SSH tunnel? This is where I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Rather distribute them for processing. You could send files to worker nodes (in a drag'n'drop manner) and delete them right after processing ends - you're no more concerned about storage.
And yeah, SCP should do the trick, e.g.:
scp [-i key.pem] <source_host>:/opt/source/mydatafile1 <target_host>:/tmp/files_to_process/mydatafile1 (PUSH or PULL)
HTTP fileserver also would:
wget <fileserver_host>[:port]/files/mydatafile1 (PULL)

Answer (score 1):

Since I miss a lot of your architecture details and your application specifics, you can take this answer as a guiding answer rather than a strict one.
You can take this approach, in the following order:

1- deploy an internal file server that stores all the files in one place and serve them

**Example:**

> http://interanal-ip-address/storage/filenameA.pdf
>
> http://interanal-ip-address/storage/filenameB.pdf
>
> http://interanal-ip-address/storage/filenameC.pdf

and so on ...

2- Install/Deploy Redis

3- Create an upload client/service/process that takes the files you want to upload and pass them to the above storage location (`/storage/`), so your files will be available once they are uploaded, at the same time push the full file path URL to a predefined Redis List/Queue (build on linked lists data structure), like this: http://internal-ip-address/storage/filenameA.pdf

You can get more details here about LPUSH and RPOP under `Redis Lists` here: http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

Examples:

1. A file upload form, that stores the files directly to storage area
2. A file upload utility/command-line/background-process, that you can create it yourself or use some existing tool to upload files to the storage location, that gets the files from specific location, be it a web address or some other server that has your files

4- Now we come to your celery workers, each one of your workers should pull (RPOP) one of the files URLs from Redis queue, download the file from your internal file server (we built in first step), and do the required processing on the way you wanted it to be.

**An important thing to note from Redis documentation:**

> Lists have a special feature that make them suitable to implement
>   queues, and in general as a building block for inter process
>   communication systems: blocking operations.
>
> However it is possible that sometimes the list is empty and there is
>   nothing to process, so RPOP just returns NULL. In this case a consumer
>   is forced to wait some time and retry again with RPOP. This is called
>   polling, and is not a good idea in this context because it has several
>   drawbacks
>
> So Redis implements commands called BRPOP and BLPOP which are versions
>   of RPOP and LPOP able to block if the list is empty: they'll return to
>   the caller only when a new element is added to the list, or when a
>   user-specified timeout is reached.

Let me know if that answers your question.

**Things to keep in mind**

- You can add as many workers as you want since this solution is very
  scalable, and your only bottleneck is Redis server, which you can make cluster of and persist your queue in case of power outage or server crash
- You can replace redis with RabbitMQ, Beanstalk, Kafka, or any other queuing/messaging system, but Redis has ben nominated in this race due to simplicity and meriad of features introduced out of the box.